# How to keep only the distinct rows of a table in postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table named Host where i keep information about the host (id,url,is_verified etc). However the problem is that the table has duplicate rows of the same host.I want to keep just one row of each host
The id is only one so i tried creating a new table with the same columns and try to provide only the disctinct one but i haven't find how.

Comment: Have you tried using DISTINCT clause on columns: url,is_verified etc.? That can be used for multiple columns.

Comment: I guess you can try to implement UNIQUE-index on the host column

Comment: Look at `distinct on (...)`: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-select.html#SQL-DISTINCT

Comment: PS If you have duplicated `id` values also, there is unique `ctid` system column: `select ctid, * from host;` https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/ddl-system-columns.html

Answer (score 0):

You can make a query like this:

```
DELETE FROM table_name
WHERE id NOT IN (
   SELECT min(id)
   FROM table_name
   GROUP BY host_columns --except id
);
```

This query get min id of each host row and delete the rest of the rows.

I understand that the id column is your primary key, if the id column is duplicated too, this query won't be useful.

Comment: As you said the id column  is my primary key but is duplicated too,thanks

Comment: So, id is not the primary key, primary key don't admit duplicated values. Use DISTINCT and copy the rows to an empty table.

Comment: i know that primary keys must be unique the problem is that i have copied the data from another table in order to have a better arraning, the are to many unique rows(6000+)

Answer (score 0):

If you want a query that returns one row per host, then use `distinct on`.  It is not clear how you are defining "host".  For instance, if you want one row per `id`, then:

```
select distinct on (id) t.*
from t
order by id;
```

Or, if `url` is how you define "host", then you would replace `id` with `url` in the query.

Note that this returns an arbitrary matching row in the table.  You can add a second key to the `order by` if there is a particular one.  For instance, if `url` defined the host and you want the largest `id`, you would use:

```
select distinct on (url) t.*
from t
order by url, id desc;
```